# Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found

Tags: laravel, autoload

Could someone tell me what exactly this error is? searched everywhere and I could find some solutions like *composer install*, *composer update*,*composer update --no-scripts*.

```
I removed the

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
and replaced it with the

$compiledPath = __DIR__.'/../vendor/compiled.php';
```

And now I have reached a point where I cant find a better solution, any help would be appreciated.

```
ttt-desktop:/var/www/html/equity3$ php artisan
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /var/www/html/equity3/bootstrap/app.php:14
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/html/equity3/artisan(24): require_once()
    #1 {main}
      thrown in /var/www/html/equity3/bootstrap/app.php on line 14
    ttt-desktop:/var/www/html/equity3$
```

I have my project in **/var/www/HTML/equity3** and I am unable to run Php artisan serve.

My autoload.php looks like this

```
// autoload.php @generated by Composer
require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit9015d85c021292bc41e4d5a5d1794f3f::getLoader();
```

Comment: Why did you remove the autoload? That's what loads in all your classes - like `Illuminate\Foundation\Application`

Comment: I didn't remove the autoload, and I have newly installed Laravel and trying to run the project.and I have tried that solution

Comment: You say explicitly in your question that you removed `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` and replaced it with sdomething else - that's why. If you have a vendor folder and that line is still in tact it should work..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did forget to do a `composer install` . :)
Or maybe something is missing in your `composer.json`.